# Getting Ignoring exception from a finished function

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm calling a third party API to send transactional SMS to the mobile numbers. While executing the function by calling from the android client, the function execution gives the code 200. But the log text shows ignoring exception from the finished function. I have seen many questions about this. None of them solved my problem and non-related to my problem.

```
'use-strict'

var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var serviceAccount = require("./ServiceKey.json");
var http = require("http");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://atithikhana2.firebaseio.com/"
});


var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": "2factor.in",
  "port": null,
  "path": "/API/V1/b5b8cefe-d3f8-11e9-ade6-0200cd936042/ADDON_SERVICES/SEND/TSMS",
  "headers": {}
};

exports.sendTNS = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => { 

 const var1 = data.var1;
 const var2 = data.var2;
 const var3 = data.var3;
 const var4 = data.var4;
 const phone_number = data.phone_number;

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];
  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });
  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.write(JSON.stringify({ From: 'AKINFO',
  To: 'phone_number',
  TemplateName: 'Customer_Template',
  VAR1: 'var1',
  VAR2: 'var2',
  VAR3: 'var3',
  vAR4: 'var4'}));
req.end();

  });
```

```
6:02:24.911 PM
sendTNS
Function execution started
6:02:24.911 PM
sendTNS
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
6:02:24.917 PM
sendTNS
Function execution took 7 ms, finished with status code: 200
6:02:24.926 PM
sendTNS
Ignoring exception from a finished function
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message and complete stack trace that you get.

Comment: added the console logs

Comment: Is your project on a paid plan? Only projects on a paid plan can call non-Google-owned URLs. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-functions%5D+Billing+account+not+configured.+External+network+is+not+accessible

Comment: Billing account not configured is appearing even in fcm message sendings. I dont think thats a problem.

Comment: Is your project on a paid plan?

Comment: No sir. I'm using spark plan.

Comment: As the warning says, calling external networks is not allowed in that case. The fact that the message also appears when calling internal networks, doesn't change that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sir, Should I pay seperately for the third party API call, Or it is enough to be in the blaze plan?

Comment: Your project needs to be on a paid plan, that is all. If you're on the Blaze/pay-as-you-go plan, you have a free quota. If you go beyond the free quota you will be charged what is described on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), but if you stay below the free quota there won't be a charge. The billing-plan requirement is purely in place to prevent abuse of Cloud Functions against 3rd party services.